# Centos 7. Freeradius fails to start on boot due to priority

Tags: startup, mariadb, freeradius, centos7

I was messing around with `FreeRADIUS` and `MySQL (MariaDB)` and it seems FreeRADIUS service can't start properly on startup. But it starts fine using `root` user or in debug mode (`radiusd -X`) and works just fine! Debug mode shows no errors.

`systemctl` command shows that radiusd.service has failed to start.

**/var/log/messages output:**

```
Aug 21 15:52:29 nexus-test systemd: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 21 15:52:29 nexus-test systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Aug 21 15:52:29 nexus-test systemd: Starting FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server....
Aug 21 15:52:29 nexus-test systemd: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Aug 21 15:52:29 nexus-test mysqld_safe: 140821 15:52:29 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Aug 21 15:52:29 nexus-test mysqld_safe: 140821 15:52:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Aug 21 15:52:30 nexus-test systemd: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Aug 21 15:52:30 nexus-test avahi-daemon[604]: Registering new address record for fe80::250:56ff:fe85:e4af on eth0.*.
Aug 21 15:52:30 nexus-test systemd: radiusd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 21 15:52:30 nexus-test systemd: Failed to start FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server..
Aug 21 15:52:30 nexus-test systemd: Unit radiusd.service entered failed state.
Aug 21 15:52:31 nexus-test kdumpctl: kexec: loaded kdump kernel
Aug 21 15:52:31 nexus-test kdumpctl: Starting kdump: [OK]
Aug 21 15:52:31 nexus-test systemd: Started Crash recovery kernel arming.
Aug 21 15:52:31 nexus-test systemd: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 21 15:52:31 nexus-test systemd: Started MariaDB database server.
```

**/var/log/radius/radius.log output:**

```
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Info: rlm_sql (sql): Driver rlm_sql_mysql (module rlm_sql_mysql) loaded and linked
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Info: rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect to database "radius"
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Info: rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (0)
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Error: rlm_sql_mysql: Couldn't connect socket to MySQL server radius@localhost:radius
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Error: rlm_sql_mysql: Mysql error 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Error: rlm_sql (sql): Opening connection failed (0)
Thu Aug 21 15:24:16 2014 : Error: /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sql[47]: Instantiation failed for module "sql"
```

After seeing this I tried to replicate the problem, killed `mariadb.service` and started to run debug mode again. And it spits out the same problem as in the `radius.log`.

I tried disabling `iptables` and `firewalld` and rebooting, but no luck:

```
systemctl disable iptables
systemctl disable firewalld
```

So maybe the problem is in the process startup order or delay of some kind. Maybe FreeRADIUS's SQL module can't connect to not yet started MariaDB? If it, how can I fix this?

In earlier versions of RHEL/CENTOS I know you easily see service start order in like rc.d or stuff, now IDK. I am new to this fancy "systemd", "systemctl", "firewalld" stuff Centos 7 introduced so sorry I'm a little bit confused. Also this new `FreeRADIUS 3` structure...

**PS.** MariaDB is enabled on startup, credentials in FR DB configuration are correct

---

**A little update:**

**cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/radiusd.service** output:

```
[Unit]
Description=FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server.
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid
ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown -R radiusd.radiusd /var/run/radiusd
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/radiusd -C
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/radiusd -d /etc/raddb
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/radiusd -C
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please add the unit you are using to start Radius.

Comment: What do you mean by unit?

Comment: I mean the systemd unit you are using to start/stop freeRadius.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you, `dawud`, you pushed me in the right direction. What I had to do here is make `radiusd.service` start AFTER `mariadb.service`.

I fired up `vim` at `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/radiusd.service` and added a line in `[Unit]` section:

```
After=mariadb.service
```

So it looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server.
After=syslog.target network.target
After=mariadb.service
```

After rebooting, FreeRADIUS started just fine.

Also [this resource](https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/) helped me a little bit.

Comment: Thank you SO much. I'm a novice sysadmin and I had this exact same problem on an Arch Linux server, and this fixed it. Saved my butt.

Answer (score 2):

You set up FreeRADIUS to connect to a local MySQL server, but that server is not running. Start the server and try again.

Comment: I know it's not running. But that happens during boot. I don't know how to make RADIUS start during boot, because MariaDB doesn't seem to start on time before RADIUS tries to connect. I CAN start it after boot, no problem